# Search index doesn't work

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am having a issue while indexing my site. I ran cron multiple times 1day ago to update all my 16000 nodes to search index. It worked fine till 73%. After 73% it stopped indexing. Next day i re-indexed search and tried to run cron from the beginning, but search index remained 0%. I have tried removing cache and few more minimal tasks and ran cron again but still it is at 0%.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: How do you refill the search index ?

Comment: i didnot refill i just re-indexed and tried to run cron again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled some module or made some change recently (after 73% of indexing)?

Check your error log, you might get answer there. 
Generally, it is because of OOM. So, increasing memory limit in php.ini can help.

You can also increase memory limit from your settings.php file by adding following line:
`ini_set('memory_limit', '225M');`

Comment: I found 2 errors after running cron in error log 
1.EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type comment. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7633 of /home/public_html/includes/common.inc).
2.PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048